# How to differentiate between Qt4.8 and Qt5.8.7

Tags: qt

I was previously using Qt4.8 for my project work. I was using it for a ARM based embedded linux device. But as Qt4.8 do not have much library support like `QSerialPort`, so I thought of downloading the latest Qt 5.8.7 and configure its compiler path as cross compiler (which I am using for ARM embedded linux device).

I downloaded the Qt4.8 by using the command `sudo apt-get install qtcreator qt4-dev-tools` so it automatically got installed. As I always need to start it as root, so I always open it using terminal and then `sudo qtcreator`.

Now I have downloaded the `Qt5.8.7 online installter` and I am installing it in home directory. I have a confusion here that if I type `sudo qtcreator` to start it, which one will get start . I do not want to remove the Qt4.8. How can I differentiate between these two.?

Comment: You can check which version is being used with `qtcreator -version`

Comment: @M.Becerra it says QT Creator 3.5.1 based on QT 5.5.1. I dont know why it says 5.5.1 when I downloaded QT4

Comment: @M.Becerra How can I start QT5.8.7 as root. I didnt find its exe in its installation path.

Comment: First of all, do you really need to start it as root? In case you really have to, use `gksudo` or `sudo -h`. Second, where did you download that *QT5.8.7 online installter*? Share the link, please

Comment: @M.Becerra From here https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-2 I downloaded the Qt Online Installer for Linux 64-bit and installed it in home

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be confusing Qt (a software development framework) with Qt Creator (an Integrated Development Environment (IDE)). Qt Creator is the default IDE for Qt, however it isn't the only IDE that can be used and doesn't have anything to do with the version of the Qt framework you are using in your own development.

When you install using the online installer, the default installation will install the latest version of the Qt framework and the latest version of Qt Creator. During this installation process, you are able to select additional Qt framework versions to install, if required. For example, you could install 5.3 and 5.8. In all the installations I've performed, a maintenance tool is also installed. This can be used at any time to add/remove/update the installed components (i.e. you could launch this after installation and add Qt 5.6 to the above). The maintenance tool is located at `{installation folder}/Qt`.

A single installation of Qt Creator can be aware of a number of different Qt versions at the same time. You configure which version it should use within each of your projects. You can view the Qt versions that Qt Creator "knows about" by selecting Tools->Options from the menu and then selecting the Build & Run option and then the Qt Versions tab. The Qt Creator that you installed using the online installer will automatically detect the versions of Qt you installed during the installation process. However, different Qt versions can also be added manually from within the same dialog.

Hope the above helps. In summary:

1. You do not need to install more than one copy of Qt Creator. If you are installing using the online installer, I would recommend running the online installer using `sudo` and installing to `/opt/`.
2. To open the Qt Creator you have installed using the online installer, you would need to browse to `{installation folder}/Qt/Tools/QtCreator/bin` and then `./qtcreator`. **You should not need to launch this using sudo**. You should also be able to launch it from the launcher or menu of your desktop.
3. To set the version(s) of the Qt framework in use for a particular project, click the project button and select/configure the versions as required.
4. The reason Qt Creator states "based on Qt 5.5.1" is because that particular version of Qt Creator was built using the Qt framework version 5.5.1.
5. I think Qt has some good documentation including guides, examples etc. This is available [here](http://doc.qt.io/).